# check if at least one of multiple object properties is true

Tags: javascript

When it comes to if statements it is possible to refactor this code

**(This is just an example and does not refer to the "real" code)**

```
if(person === 'customer' || person === 'employee' || person === 'other')
```

to

```
if(person === ('customer' || 'employee' || 'other'))
```

---

Currently I have an object called `state` containing 3 boolean properties. I want to show an overlay if at least one property returns `true`. My current solution is this

```
showOverlay: state => state.isNavigating || state.isHttpRequesting || state.isProcessing
```

and I'm asking if there is a way to clean it up. Pseudo code would be

```
showOverlay: state => (isNavigating || isHttpRequesting || isProcessing) of state
```

I know there is not a big gain out of it, but it would remove all the `state. ...` parts.

Comment: `it is possible to refactor this code` no, it isn't, they are two different results

Comment: `['customer', 'employee', 'other'].includes(person)` but that's quite different from your other code

Comment: @CertainPerformance - OP states that the second piece of code **IS** valid refactoring of the first!

Comment: `state.isNavigating || state.isHttpRequesting || state.isProcessing` is very readable. You could probably destructure the properties and then use OR but that's an additional step

Comment: `This is just an example and does not refer to the "real" code` - that's not what you said, you said the first two pieces of code are the same

Comment: `state => { with(state) { return isNavigating || isHttpRequesting || isProcessing; } }` ... just kidding :)

Comment: "is there a way to clean it up" ... to be honest: the code is actually really clean, what else do you want :)

Comment: I'm sorry but `premature optimization is the root of all evil` is my biggest enemy for now .. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an array of property names, and check whether `some` of them are truthy:

```
showOverlay: state => ['isNavigating', 'isHttpRequesting', 'isProcesing'].some(prop => state[prop]);
```

Maybe it's more DRY, which is arguably good, but it's a bit less readable when there are only 3 properties IMO, which is arguably bad.

Comment: thanks, what about performance? Is it bad to create an array and loop through it?

Comment: On modern computers, performance is almost never something to worry about unless you've run a performance test and have identified a section of code causing a bottleneck - don't worry about it. Clean, readable code is better by default. (though, is this clean and readable? Up to you. Maybe if there were 4+ properties, I would definitely prefer the array, but I'm not so sure if there are only 3)